# Estimation of copula for discrete random variable

Tags: correlation, copula

I'm interested in the estimation of parameter of copula for discrete random variables.

The problem is described as follow:
I have 30 discrete random variables $X_1,.., X_{30}$, each random variable is Poisson distributed, and I assume that they correlates by a copula. Now i want to estimate the parameter of that copula base on the data of these 30 random variables.

Could you please tell me which method to be use ? For now, the maximum likelihood estimation fails because it requires a lot of computing time in the case of discrete random variable.

Thank you very much for your help!